# Displaying Marker Values Within a MatLab Plot

Tags: matlab, plot, markers

I'm trying to display my values for a given vector within a plot.  My code is:

```
x = [0.1 0.2 -0.1 4.1 -2 1.5 -0.1];
plot(x)
a = num2str(x(:));
b = cellstr(a);
c = strtrim(b);
text(x,y,c);
```

Its plotting the values, but they are scattered all over the place, and not sitting nicely next to each point on the graph.

Comment: If you do `plot(x)` your x coordinates are going to be the indices of your array and your y coordinates are going to be the value of `x` at that index. You're telling MATLAB to put the text at negative `x` values when, as written, there are none in the plot (there is no such thing as a negative index).

Comment: Well, have you actually tried to run the code? I can tell you that the code did not run since `y` was not defined. Try to define both `x` and `y` and if the text is still not placed in the right location so come back.

Comment: So, would I need to create a vector `x` axis with the values `1` to `7` and then create the above vector as `y`, then `plot(x,y)`, then run the `text` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, calling [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) with a single vector input treats the values of the vector as the y-coordinates and their indices as the x-coordinates. Your provided `x` vector contains negative numbers, but your `plot` call only has one vector input, so there will be no negative x-coordinates in the plot (there are no negative indices in MATLAB).

Assuming your `x` vector is your desired y-coordinate, the following example will provide the behavior I'm guessing you're expecting:

```
y = [0.1 0.2 -0.1 4.1 -2 1.5 -0.1];
x = 1:1:length(y);
plot(x,y)
a = num2str(x(:));
b = cellstr(a);
c = strtrim(b);
h = text(x,y,c);
```

Where `h` is an array of object handles that you can use with [`get`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) and [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) to query and modify the [properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html) of each individual text object (like size, alignment, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, was going to suggest answering so I could accept.  All okay now :-)

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling num2str on y?